# When does javascript called from jquery.ready() run relative to scripts in <head>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript passed to [jQuery.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) will run after the DOM is fully loaded but doesn't wait for all assets such as images to be received (unlike [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)). Cool. But will javascript placed in `<script>` tags in the `<head>` of a document always run before code passed to jQuery.ready()?

I'm assuming the answer is yes, but couldn't find anything specifically clarifying this.

Comment: Not if you use `setTimeout` ;)

Comment: Yes, the <script> tags them selves and the code within them will be executed first if they are higher in the DOM than other script tags. What happens within that code may or may not happen first due to what events the code could possibly be bound to, such as a click event that may never happen or the $.ready() method which may take longer to execute than code elsewhere on the page depending on the browser and webpage.

Comment: agree with Kevin B, but again lots of stuff depends on what that script does. your alert may be executed, but a long script won't finish. why are you asking that? can you give us the case you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts in script tags run in sequential order in the order they are encountered in the HTML file.  So, a script in the HEAD tag runs as soon as the HEAD section of the document is loaded and no scripts after that run until that script has finished executing.

Scripts containing `$(document).ready(fn)` will schedule their callback to run later after the whole document has been loaded.

So, since a script in the HEAD section is long BEFORE the body of the document has loaded, scripts in the HEAD section will run before a callback specified using `$(document).ready()` is run.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code is executed the moment the `script` tag is reached by the browser when parsing the document. `jquery.ready` waits for the whole DOM to be until the whole document is parsed, so yes it is run before your code you passed to `jquery.ready` regardless of it being in the head or body.